# Does natural earth have all cities information?

Tags: natural-earth

I downloaded `Populated Place` cultural data across all the large, medium and small scale data from Natural Earth https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

Then I visualised the shape files in QGIS tool.There are total 8,836 cities details listed.

But as per https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities , we have total 4.4 million populated places.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on https://www.naturalearthdata.com/features/ , https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/110m-populated-places/ , https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/50m-populated-places/ and https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-populated-places/ ?

Comment: The numbers you indicate already seem to indicate an indirect answer to the question: no. However, what does "all" cities actually mean at all? What is your definition of a city? Depending on context, people can understand quite different things referring to "city". So the question is not precise enough to give an answer other than just "no".

Comment: Since Natural Earth is open data, I think your question about its compilation would be better asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-populated-places/) says:

> Point symbols with name attributes. Includes **all** admin-0 and **many**
> admin-1 capitals, major cities and towns, plus a **sampling** of smaller
> towns in sparsely inhabited regions. We favor regional significance
> over population census in determining our selection of places

So no, not every city will be included.

Moreover there is a big difference between a city and a populated place. For example, for administrative reasons, many small populated places can be agglomerated into a single city.

PS: and for what it's worth, I live in the 4th city of my province in terms of population, but there is no point in Natural Earth because the country's capital is just across the river.